# Mate Panel extras

Tags: panel

I found out about the fish that tells you your fortune, but I also found out there was more then one type of them. [Like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHKJd.jpg) 
But I wanna know is there any thing that is like this? Maybe one that doesn't crack corny jokes and weird quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Wanda the Fish indicator](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/catch-of-the-day-wanda-the-fish-indicator-applet) which apparently tells fortune.

The installation can be done either by adding the ppa (ppa:dylanmccall/indicator-fish) or via downloading `deb` file for your OS bit version ( amd-64 package for 64 bit os , and i386 for 32-bit os)

To add ppa , do

```
sudo bash -c 'apt-add-repository ppa:dylanmccall/indicator-fish && apt-get update && apt-get install indicator-fish
```

Links for the deb files are provided in the linked article, which point to the [launchpad page of the project](https://launchpad.net/~dylanmccall/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-fish)